# Thread Scheduler picking a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

The code snippet given below gives different outputs on running it two different times. In the first case it gives the "output 1" and in second case it gives the "output 2". I don't understand that if the thread scheduler picks the `m1` thread then without completing its `run()` method how can it start the `m2` thread. Can anyone explain to me what exactly is happening here? And why do I get "output 1" sometimes and "output 2" other times? I think "output 1" is the correct output.

```
class TestMultiPriority1 extends Thread
{  
 public void run()
 {  
  System.out.println("running thread name is:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());  
  System.out.println("running thread priority is:"+Thread.currentThread().getPriority());  
 }  
 public static void main(String args[])
 {  
  TestMultiPriority1 m1=new TestMultiPriority1();  
  TestMultiPriority1 m2=new TestMultiPriority1();  
  m1.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);  
  m2.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);  
  m1.start();  
  m2.start();  
  }  
}
```

output 1:

```
running thread name is:Thread-0
running thread priority is:1
running thread name is:Thread-1
running thread priority is:10
```

output 2:

```
running thread name is:Thread-0
running thread name is:Thread-1
running thread priority is:1
running thread priority is:10
```

Comment: The thing about correctness is that it's your job as a developer to define what is correct. We don't "think" that something is correct, we know what is correct in advance and make sure the program behaves that way. This is especially important with multi-threading where such constraints must be defined through [synchronization, locks or other mechanisms](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html). If you just start two threads in parallel without those constraints, you can't make any assumptions about their relative timing. And setting priority won't change that.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand that if the thread scheduler picks the m1 thread then without completing it's run() method how can it start the m2 thread.

It doesn't. The original thread that created the `m1` thread, which is probably still running, creates the `m2` thread. Once both threads have been created, they can both run if the machine has sufficient cores. Even if it doesn't, the scheduler can switch threads at any time it wants to.

Neither output is incorrect. They just result from different scheduler decisions.